# Change an image to a new image with Javascript each time the image is clicked

Tags: javascript, css, onclick, background-image, addeventlistener

I have a folder of images and I want to replace the one currently being displayed with another image each time that it is clicked on.

I've managed to make this happen once - i.e. to make the if statement work, but I can't get to the elif statement. Why is the elif condition not being met. Everytime I click it just repeats the if statement, even though the console log shows that the backgroundImage is now budgies: url("http://localhost:3000/images_diamonds/budgies.jpg")

```
// For clicking on the image
document.querySelector('.diamond-pic').addEventListener('click', () => {
    
  let elem = document.getElementById('pic1');
  let ht = window.getComputedStyle(elem, null).getPropertyValue("background");
  console.log(ht)


  if (document.getElementById('pic1').style.backgroundImage="url(../../images_diamonds/ghecko.jpg)") {
    document.getElementById("pic1").style.backgroundImage = "url('../../images_diamonds/budgies.jpg'";
    console.log('if achieved')

  } else if (document.getElementById('pic1').style.backgroundImage="url(../../images_diamonds/budgies.jpg)") {
    document.getElementById("pic1").style.backgroundImage = "url('../../images_diamonds/Christmas_Beetle.jpg'";
    console.log('else if achived')

  } else {
    console.log('else achieved')
  }
});
```

Comment: Look at the background you entered in the question: `url("http://localhost:3000/images_diamonds/budgies.jpg")`. Now compare it, character by character, with what is entered in your code `url(../../images_diamonds/budgies.jpg)`. Not the same, right? Also, `==` is used for comparison. `=` is used for assignment. So your `if` conditions are assigning the background image rather than comparing them.

Comment: It would be better if you used another attribute to trigger the image change, like a `data-` attribute. Then you wouldn't have to use `getComputedStyle()`, which is actually kind of slow (relatively).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is to keep the image names in an array and then just advance the image to the next one in the array when it's clicked.

```js
let counter = 0;
let imgs = [
  "https://static4.depositphotos.com/1026550/376/i/600/depositphotos_3763236-stock-photo-gold-star.jpg",
  "https://previews.123rf.com/images/lineartestpilot/lineartestpilot1803/lineartestpilot180302423/96543894-cartoon-shooting-star.jpg",
  "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTk5tGujYXbv4f9A0pvSuOWC6IhljTzmy4WBw&usqp=CAU",
  "http://www.webweaver.nu/clipart/img/nature/planets/smiling-gold-star.png",
  "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/34/Red_star.svg/2000px-Red_star.svg.png"
];

document.querySelector("img").addEventListener("click", function(event){
  this.src = imgs[counter];
  // As long as the counter is less than the last index in the array
  // increase the counter. Otherwise, start over.
  counter = counter < imgs.length-1 ? counter+1 : 0;
});
```

```css
img { width: 200px;}
```

```html
<img src="https://previews.123rf.com/images/lineartestpilot/lineartestpilot1802/lineartestpilot180274309/95545188-shooting-star-decorative-cartoon.jpg">
```

And here's an example when the images are used as backgrounds:

```js
let counter = 0;
let imgs = [
  "https://static4.depositphotos.com/1026550/376/i/600/depositphotos_3763236-stock-photo-gold-star.jpg",
  "https://previews.123rf.com/images/lineartestpilot/lineartestpilot1803/lineartestpilot180302423/96543894-cartoon-shooting-star.jpg",
  "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTk5tGujYXbv4f9A0pvSuOWC6IhljTzmy4WBw&usqp=CAU",
  "http://www.webweaver.nu/clipart/img/nature/planets/smiling-gold-star.png",
  "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/34/Red_star.svg/2000px-Red_star.svg.png"
];

document.querySelector("div").addEventListener("click", function(event){
  this.style.background = "url(" + imgs[counter] + ")";
  // As long as the counter is less than the last index in the array
  // increase the counter. Otherwise, start over.
  counter = counter < imgs.length-1 ? counter+1 : 0;
});
```

```css
div { width: 300px;
      height:300px; border:1px solid black;  background:url("https://previews.123rf.com/images/lineartestpilot/lineartestpilot1802/lineartestpilot180274309/95545188-shooting-star-decorative-cartoon.jpg");
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: This array answer looks great but I'm struggling to apply it to my case where the pictures are being shown with  style background: url(""); rather than <img src=">

Comment: @Frankie Updated answer to show that scenario.